# ‘cout’ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I was learning Adam Drozdek's book "Data Structures and Algorithms in C++", well, I typed the code in page 15 in my vim and compiled it in terminal of my Ubuntu 11.10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        age = a;
    }
};

Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1);
cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy");
node2.name = 30;
cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
```

But there's some error:

```
oo@oo:~$ g++ unproper.cpp -o unproper
unproper.cpp:15:23: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
unproper.cpp:16:1: error: ‘cout’ does not name a type
unproper.cpp:17:7: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
unproper.cpp:18:1: error: ‘node2’ does not name a type
unproper.cpp:19:1: error: ‘cout’ does not name a type
```

I have searched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846333/c-does-not-name-to-a-type),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153782/c-does-not-name-a-type),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810773/error-does-not-name-a-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597605/c-struct-does-not-name-a-type), but I can't find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Where's `main()`?

Comment: You're missing your main. The code is outside of a function and is considered by the compiler to be either a declaration of variables, class, structs or other such commands. Just put all of the bottom code into int main()

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem is that the code you have that does the printing is outside of any function.  Statements that aren't declarations in C++ need to be inside a function.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
    
struct Node{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        age = a;
    }
};


int main() {
    Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1);
    cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
    strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy");
    node2.name = 30;
    cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
}
```

Comment: why printing should be in function only ?

Comment: It’s part of a more general rule that only declaration statements can appear outside of functions in C++. I don’t know if there’s a deep philosophical reason for that or whether it’s a historical artifact.

Comment: @ templatetypedef okay

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the function declaration around your program code. The following should solve your error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        age = a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1);
    cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
    strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy");
    node2.name = 30;
    cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
}
```

The error you then get (something like "invalid conversion from int to char*") is because you try to set an integer value (30) to a string attribute (name) with

```
node2.name=30;
```

I think

```
node2.age=30;
```

would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

`main()` function is missed.There should be a `main()` function in C++ ,and you should put `cout` into a function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cout outside the function you can do it by collecting the value returned by cout in boolean.see the below example

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool b=cout<<"1";

int main()
{

return 0;

}
```

output:

```
error prog.cpp:4:14: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_ostream<char>' to 'bool' in initialization
 bool b=cout<<"1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Including:

```
int main()
{ //code 
  return 0;
}
```

will help you. This problem usually occurs to those who are learning from book in which they usually don't use main function after a few chapters.

Answer (score 0):

for Class Error : you Should Use the cout inside any method of the class.You cannot use cout openly in any class.

```
class result:public exam{
public:

    display_result()
    {
    float percentage;
    percentage=(physics + maths) / 2;
    get_roll_number();
    getmarks();
    cout << "The Final Percentage of the Student is =" <<percentage<< "%" << endl;
    }
};
```