# Assigning structure variable a value

Tags: c++, c, struct, structure

When i assign value to s.rollno in this way it doesnot work

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student{
int rollno;
int marks;
}s  ;
s.rollno = 2;

int main(){

printf("%d",s.rollno);

}
```

BUt if i assign value to s.rollno in main it works

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student{
int rollno;
int marks;
}s  ;

int main(){
s.rollno = 2;


printf("%d",s.rollno);

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with structures. You can't do `int i; i = 2;` outside of a function. You can't do much of anything besides declare things.

Comment: You cannot have such code outside any function scope.

Comment: Read the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363664/cant-use-structure-in-global-scope

Answer (score 3):

you cannot write

```
 s.rollno = 2;
```

in global scope, as  a separate statement. All the statements needs to appear inside some function , which can *execute* them.

However, you can initialize the value at the time of definition, like

```
struct student {
    int rollno;
    int marks;
} s = {.rollno = 2};
```

Comment: i can declare a variable globally outside main

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you please check the initialization syntax, I just cant remember it exactly...

Comment: @IshanBansal in simple words.... because every statement needs to be executed, and a statement outside a function is invalid, as that cannot be executed _ever_ (take the analogy, don;t take the conecpt, it is for ease of understanding only.)

Comment: @NatashaDutta, It's fine for C99. C++ would (could) be `= {2};` if doing it like that.

Comment: @IshanBansal, I suppose Dennis Ritchie could have designed C like that, but he didn't. Decisions like that have to be made while designing a language. Python (possibly every scripting language) chose the other way. It's along the same lines of how Java requires classes around everything and C++ doesn't.

Comment: @IshanBansal: Because if you don't write the statement inside a function, _when_ should it be executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable outside of a function scope like this:

```
int a;
int main() {
   a = 5;
}
```

But you cannot set it like you do. This is because of the difference between runtime and compile time. Global variables are created and set to memory and this is determined at compile time. But code like `a=5` above is performed at run time. Imagine this situation:

```
int a;
a = somestruct.somefunction();
```

Without a function to run this in, how can we be sure what a is? Things done outside the scope of a function cannot occur at run time.