# Compilation trivia : error ' ... ' does not name a type

Tags: c++, typedef

I know this question has been asked before here. But i just cannot get it right. (may be one of those times!) . Anyways here is a simple code of linked list

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct nodeType {
               int data;
               struct nodeType *next;
         }node;

typedef node *list;

list temp = new nodeType();
temp->data = 5;
```

I am not able to compile this simple piece of code!

```
g++ -g -c list.cpp
error: ‘temp’ does not name a type
```

Comment: You cannot have standalone expressions in namespace scope. `temp->data = 5;` needs to be inside some function.

Comment: `typedef node *list;` should be `typedef nodeType *list;`, also remove `typedef` before and `node` after the struct declaration.

Comment: `list temp = new nodeType();  void fn() { temp->data = 5; }` will compile.

Comment: There are a multitude of questions similar to this. Search for "[c++] does not name a type" and things like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935027/cout-does-not-name-a-type) will be found in short order.

Comment: the code is a curious mix of C, C++ and invalid.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct nodeType {
               int data;
               struct nodeType *next;
         }node;
```

Not necessary in C++ since elaborate type specifiers are not necessary anymore.

```
struct nodeType 
{
     int data;
     nodeType *next;
};
```

Of course the corresponding `typedef` has to be adjusted.

---

```
list temp = new nodeType();
temp->data = 5;
```

All *statements* have to go inside a function like `main`, and you should `delete` the node afterwards;

```
int main()
{
    list temp = new nodeType; // braces not necessary
    temp->data = 5;
    delete temp;
}
```

Or put it inside a Smart-Pointer directly. Or even better: Write a class which uses RAII to create and destroy the nodes. Which is basically [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: "All *statements* have to go inside a main function," -- I'm pretty sure you didn't mean what you wrote. You can of course have other functions than main.

Comment: Haha, sorry, i meant to say "all *statements* have to go inside a function like `main`" :D

Comment: So what? I just wanted to clarify that you generally have to destroy every object with dynamic storage duration yourself. It seems like the guy who wrote this post is a beginner who doesn't even know that. I'm sure he'll find out that the OS frees all your memory after the program terminates later by himself.