# Conditional compilation, error: 'cout' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I'm learning about header guards from http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/110-a-first-look-at-the-preprocessor-and-header-guards/ tutorial.
Before explaining the idea of header guards the author used this code (which I copied to my program) to explain the idea of conditional compilation.

```
#include <iostream>
#define PRINT_JOE
using namespace std;
#ifdef PRINT_JOE
cout << "Joe" << endl;
#endif

#ifdef PRINT_BOB
cout << "Bob" << endl;
#endif

int main()
{

}
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test_programs\header_guards.cpp|5|error: 'cout' does not name a type|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

An author of a tutorial stated that PRINT_JOE will compile because it's #defined while PRINT_BOB will not because it was not #defined. But the compiler gives an error. I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935027/cout-does-not-name-a-type) that statements in C++ need to be inside a function. But one does not use he #define directive inside int main(). I am using gnu gcc compiler.

Comment: `using namespace std;` it will solve it probably

Comment: Your cout is appearing outside all functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cout` statements have to be in a function. Of the top of my head the only things that can be in global scope are global variable declarations and preprocessor directives. That means the `#define` or `#ifdef` alone would be fine, all the `cout` stuff won't be.

```
#include <iostream>
#define PRINT_JOE

int main()
{

    #ifdef PRINT_JOE
    std::cout << "Joe" << std::endl;
    #endif

    #ifdef PRINT_BOB
    std::cout << "Bob" << std::endl;
    #endif

}
```

Also it's `std::cout` and `std::endl`

Comment: it's not necessarly `std::` in front. `using namespace std;` is correct  as well.

Comment: @Kai indeed, he had neither in his first version though and I prever to recommeend the `std::` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

put your cout calls int he main function

```
 #include <iostream>
 #define PRINT_JOE
 using namespace std;


int main()
{
   #ifdef PRINT_BOB
   cout << "Bob" << endl;
   #endif
   #ifdef PRINT_JOE
   cout << "Joe" << endl;
   #endif

   return 0; 
}
```