# When i compile and build this code i get this message error 'node1' does not name a type

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

struct listNode{
int student_Num;
int grade;
listNode *next;
};

typedef listNode * studentCollection;
studentCollection sc;


listNode * node1 = new listNode;
node1->studentNum = 1001; node1->grade = 78;
listNode * node2 = new listNode;
node2->studentNum = 1012; node2->grade = 93;
listNode * node3 = new listNode;
node3->studentNum = 1076; node3->grade = 85;
sc = node1;
node1->next = node2;
node2->next = node3;
node3->next = NULL;
node1 = node2 = node3 = NULL;
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

I get this error message when i tries to build and compile error 'node1' does not name a type i tried to google this on earlier questions and [‘cout’ does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935027/cout-does-not-name-a-type)
What is wrong i working on Codeblocks does this ide make this error message

Comment: 1. Move assignments inside `main()`, 2. change `node1->studentNum` to `node1->student_Num` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your list initialization code into a function (into `main()` for example).

Note: You can, for example, define global variables outside of functions (almost always a bad idea) but you can not write code outside of functions.

And `student_Num` is not `studentNum`.

What is `node1 = node2 = node3 = NULL;` for? Consider using `delete` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @sergej i didnt work: now figure out why or downvote the question :)