# Global Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, global, cout

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in the following code when I initialize a global array and want to print its value outside main() function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int global_array[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};

cout << global_array[2];

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" ;
}
```

The error keep popping is

```
error: 'cout' does not name a type|
```

Comment: cout has to be inside the main or atleast in cpp classes that declared out side of main or even a functions if you like so,

Comment: It seems you are confusing C++ with languages like PHP or JavaScript. What do you *expect* to happen in your program? Do you expect the array to be printed first and "Hello World!" second? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

The statement `cout << global_array[2];` is not a declaration (it is an expression). Only declarations are allowed outside of functions.

So, if you want to print anything outside of `main` function, you can only do so by having the expression within another function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the code you have that does the printing is outside of any function. Statements in C++ need to be inside a function. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void hello();

int global_array[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};

void hello()
{
cout << global_array[2];
}

int main()
{
hello();
cout << "Hello World!" ;
}
```

Before asking a question, you can search: [‘cout’ does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935027/cout-does-not-name-a-type)

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call it from outside the main it should be in a function something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int global_array[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};

int pre()
{
    cout << global_array[2];
    return 0;
}

int x = pre();

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i mentioned it on comment it can be done via c++ classes.

```
#include <iostream>

int global_array[5] = { 10,20,30,40,50 };

struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << global_array[2] << std::endl;
    }
};

foo f;

int main()
{
}
```