# assigning values to global variables in C++

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I am wondering why assigning value to a global variable will result in error

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 5;
x = 3; // error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

Haven't I just declared it on the line above? Well, let's see if x exists;

```cpp
int x = 5;
int x = 3; // error: redefinition of 'x'
```

Okey, so it does agree that x is defined, but the type is "not yet" an int. Can someone explain this behavior, what do you call this behavior? how does it happen? why is it designed this way?

Comment: You can only perform assignment in the context of a function.

Comment: In less esoteric terms than some of the other answers, you can't assign to a variable outside of a function unless you're assigning an initial value. You must do that inside a function.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of [c++ - ‘cout’ does not name a type - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935027/cout-does-not-name-a-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x = 3;` is an *expression statement*. Expression statements can only appear at block scope, i.e. inside a function body.

At namespace scope (global scope / file scope) you can only have declarations/definitions, which assignment is not.

Comment: Interesting, I look at two different C++ tutorials, and non of them have mentioned about this rule. Could you shed some light on why it is designed this way?

Comment: @YiLuo Why would you want statements like this in global scope?

Comment: Global variables are dangerous enough. I don't want to know what the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) would look like with global expressions.

Comment: @YiLuo C++ programs, unlike e.g. Python, are not executed top to bottom. Execution starts with the `main` function. So if you do want to do anything at the beginning of the program, you should put it inside the `main` function. The initializer's in global variable definitions such as `= 5` in `int x = 5;` are an exception. They are executed before `main` is entered, but they are generally not executed in any particular order. So in conclusion there is no point in having statements at global scope.

Comment: @YiLuo As mentioned in the comment above you should try to avoid using global variables at all. They are very tricky to handle correctly. Instead define your variables at the point where you need them first and pass them on by-reference to functions. The only exception to this advice are `const`/`constexpr` global variables, which are often fine.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
 int x = 5;
 x = 3; // error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

In first case you mentioned, `int x = 5;` is a variable definition and initializing process. Global variables could be defined outside a function, but the value assignment only be done in function.

```cpp
int x = 5;
int x = 3; // error: redefinition of 'x'
```

After you add `int` before `x = 3`, the variable x is already defined, and its data type also be specified. You can't redefine it.

Answer (score 1):

you only define and declare a variable in global but you can not put statements 
 and expression in global.

```
 int x = 5;
 x = 3; //expression
```

and When `x=3` executed?. but you can initialize it by

```
 int x = 5;
```

this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

> `error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations`

In other words, your choices for what to put at this location in the code are limited. Among the valid choices, a declaration is closest to what you wrote. If you add a type specifier, then you would have a declaration. It would be a re-definition, but at least the syntax fits this part of the code.

The implication is that an assignment is not a valid choice at this point in the code. Assignments (as opposed to definitions that use `=`) can occur only inside functions.

It looks like clang produces that particular error message. You might find gcc's to be less ambiguous: `error: 'x' does not name a type`.

> Haven't I just declared it on the line above?

The error message for using an undeclared variable looks more like `error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'`. You didn't get this message, so it is premature to conclude that `x` is not declared at this point. Noticing details like this is a useful skill when debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In fact, I can conclude from these two error messages that assignments are not allowed outside of functions. More of my interest is in why it is not allowed. My intuition tells me that there is a purpose behind, whether it is for easier parsing, consistency of some principles, or some historical factors.

Comment: @YiLuo The purpose behind it would be a separate question. As some prep work for such a question, you might want to look at the ahead-of-time compiled (not [JIT compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)) [structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) languages and see how many of them support this sort of statement outside functions/procedures.