# Declare and define a char pointer variable on different lines in C++ (does not name a type)?

Tags: c++

I have a script that attempts to identify the word `__version__` at the beginning of a line (i.e. `^__version__` as regex) in a text file, and replaces its assignment with a current date string; and I would like to reuse this script unchanged in C++.

So in this case, I would not want to write `const char* __version__ = "...";` because in that case, the script regex wouldn't match. So I tried declaring the variable on one line, then assigning it on the next line, as so:

```c++
#include <iostream>

char* __version__;
__version__ = "2024-02-06";

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

But compiling this fails with "error: ‘**version**’ does not name a type".

Of course, if I move the assignment `__version__ = "2024-02-06";` then the code with compile (albeit with "warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’"), but I was wondering - is it somehow possible to "cheat" the compiler, so I can write `__version__ = "2024-02-06";` outside of a function - during variable initialization, and even have it set as a const?

Comment: Names starting with double underscore are reserved. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: String literal are basically of array type `const char[N]` and so they decay to `const char*`. So we can't(and shouldn't) assign a string literal like `"Hello"` to a `char*` in any case.

Comment: [Why is conversion from string literal to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

Comment: Just split the definition over two lines. That is, delete `__version__;`

Comment: @user12002570 That is true, but on most compilers it's "only" a warning. The reason this fails to compile is that an assignment statement cannot exist outside a function.

Comment: @perivesta In that case, I've added another dupe to the dupe list [assigning values to global variables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896812/assigning-values-to-global-variables-in-c)

Comment: -> `std::string __version__;`

Comment: line breaks are immaterial to the code, if you script expects a line break, just add one https://godbolt.org/z/KKr1ne4Ef

Comment: You're trying to write python when you're writing C++, which is a terrible idea to begin with. Then you're using an extremely rudimentary and brittle method of parsing the bad C++. Please don't.

Answer (score -4):

Ok, got this solved with preprocessor, while writing the question - but it would be nice to have a proper explanation of why I cannot just split declaration and definition on two line...  Otherwise working code is:

```c++
#include <iostream>

#define MYVERSION \
__version__ = "2024-02-06"
const char* MYVERSION;

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World " << __version__ << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, all that code does is `const char * __version__ = "2024-02-06";`.  A macro is nothing more than a text replacement.

Comment: *proper explanation of why I cannot just split declaration and definition on two line* - Because C++ doesn't work this way on a fundamental level. C++ consists of statements and declarations. Declarations can be placed in namespace scope, statements can only be placed in function body. `const char* __version__;` is a declaration, `const char* __version__ = "asdf";` is a declaration, but `__version__ = "asdf";` is a statement.